# My JavaScript Particle Collision Engine Failing to render, "Particle is not a constructor" Error

Tags: javascript, constructor, html5-canvas

I have the following code in which I attempt to create an engine for basic particle collisions. However, it is failing to render and leaves an empty canvas with the error: "Particle is not a constructor". Please aid in solving this problem, as well as suggestions for the engine.

I have tried changing the temporary 'Particle' variable to 'p'. My code is as follows:

```
var Canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    Canvas.width = 300;
    Canvas.height = 300;
    Canvas.style = 'border: 1px solid black';
    document.body.appendChild(Canvas);
    
var CTX = Canvas.getContext('2d');
    
var ParticleIndex = [];

function Particle(X, Y, Xvel, Yvel, Size, Xfric, Yfric, Xacc, Yacc, Bounce){
    
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
    this.XVel = Xvel;
    this.YVel = Yvel;
    this.Size = Size;
    this.Xfric = Xfric;
    this.Yfric = Yfric;
    this.Xacc = Xacc;
    this.Yacc = Yacc;
    this.Bounce = Bounce
    
    this.appendToIndex = function(){
        
        ParticleIndex.push(this);
        
    }
    
    this.Render = function(){
        
        CTX.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, this.Size, this.Size);
        
    }; 
    
    this.Physics = function(){
        
        this.X += this.Xvel;
        
        for(var i = 0; i < ParticleIndex.length; i++){
            
            if(isCollide(this, ParticleIndex[i])){
                
                this.X -= this.Xvel
                this.Xvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        this.Y += this.Yvel;
        
        for(var i = 0; i < ParticleIndex.length; i++){
            
            if(isCollide(this, ParticleIndex[i])){
                
                this.Y -= this.Yvel
                this.Yvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        this.Xvel *= this.Xfric;
        this.Yvel *= this.Yfric;
        
    }
    
    
}

function isCollide(a, b) {
    
    return !(
        
        ((a.Y + a.Size) < (b.Y)) ||
        (a.Y > (b.Y + b.Size)) ||
        ((a.X + a.Size) < b.X) ||
        (a.X > (b.X + b.Size))
        
    );
    
}

function Render(){
    
    CTX.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
    
    for(var k = 0; k < ParticleIndex.length; k++){
        
        ParticleIndex[k].Physics;
        ParticleIndex[k].Render;
        
    }
    
}

for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    
    var p = new Particle(
        
        Math.round(Math.random() * Canvas.width), 
        Math.round(Math.random() * Canvas.height),
        (Math.random * 10) - 5,
        (Math.random * 10) - 5,
        5,
        0.9,
        0.9,
        0,
        0,
        0.8
    
    )
    
    p.appendToIndex();    
    p.Render();
    
}

alert('Rendering...');

Render()
```

The following part gives the error:

```
for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    
    var p = new Particle(
        
        Math.round(Math.random() * Canvas.width), 
        Math.round(Math.random() * Canvas.height),
        (Math.random * 10) - 5,
        (Math.random * 10) - 5,
        5,
        0.9,
        0.9,
        0,
        0,
        0.8
    
    )
    
    p.appendToIndex();    
    p.Render();
    
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing `()` for the function calls ( a few of them), and the function `Physics()` doesn't work well, yet – it is because bad variable names (`XVel` vs `Xvel`). And the final bonus, you can't collide with yourself therefore added that condition to `isCollide`.

Other Issues you might have are the boundaries (update: I did some checking for this case), and time factor, you should have variable `t` which will increase according to time passed, not according to frequency of timeout.

Also consider using a library for this, such as [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/)

```js
var Canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

Canvas.width = 400;
Canvas.height = 180;
Canvas.style = 'border: 1px solid black';
document.body.appendChild(Canvas);

var CTX = Canvas.getContext('2d');

var ParticleIndex = [];

function Particle(X, Y, Xvel, Yvel, Size, Xfric, Yfric, Xacc, Yacc, Bounce) {

  this.X = X;
  this.Y = Y;
  this.Xvel = Xvel;
  this.Yvel = Yvel;
  this.Size = Size;
  this.Xfric = Xfric;
  this.Yfric = Yfric;
  this.Xacc = Xacc;
  this.Yacc = Yacc;
  this.Bounce = Bounce

  this.appendToIndex = function() {

    ParticleIndex.push(this);

  }

  this.Render = function() {

    CTX.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, this.Size, this.Size);

  };

  this.Physics = function() {

    this.X += this.Xvel;

    for (var i = 0; i < ParticleIndex.length; i++) {

      if (isCollide(this, ParticleIndex[i])) {

        this.X -= this.Xvel
        this.Xvel *= this.Bounce * -1;

      }

    }

    this.Y += this.Yvel;

    for (var i = 0; i < ParticleIndex.length; i++) {

      if (isCollide(this, ParticleIndex[i])) {

        this.Y -= this.Yvel
        this.Yvel *= this.Bounce * -1;

      }

    }

    this.Xvel *= this.Xfric;
    this.Yvel *= this.Yfric;

    // boundaries
    if (this.X < 0) {
      this.X = 0
      this.Xvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
    }
    if (this.Y < 0) {
      this.Y = 0
      this.Yvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
    }
    if (this.X + this.Size > Canvas.width - 1) {
      this.X = Canvas.width - this.Size - 1
      this.Xvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
    }
    if (this.Y + this.Size > Canvas.height - 1) {
      this.Y = Canvas.height - this.Size - 1
      this.Yvel *= this.Bounce * -1;
    }

  }

}

function isCollide(a, b) {
  if (a == b) {
    return false
  }

  return !(

    ((a.Y + a.Size) < (b.Y)) ||
    (a.Y > (b.Y + b.Size)) ||
    ((a.X + a.Size) < b.X) ||
    (a.X > (b.X + b.Size))
  );

}

function Render() {

  CTX.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);

  for (var k = 0; k < ParticleIndex.length; k++) {

    ParticleIndex[k].Physics();
    ParticleIndex[k].Render();

  }

  requestAnimationFrame(Render)

}

for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

  var Size = 12;
  var p = new Particle(

    Math.round(Math.random() * (Canvas.width - Size)),
    Math.round(Math.random() * (Canvas.height - Size)),
    (Math.random() * 10) - 5,
    (Math.random() * 10) - 5,
    Size,
    0.999,
    0.999,
    0,
    0,
    1

  )

  p.appendToIndex();
  // p.Render();

}


Render()
```